# Setting a char array from the struct with another char array

Tags: c, methods, struct, char, arrays

I have the struct:

```
struct person {
    char firstname[];
};
```

And the method:

```
void abcde (person* a, char firstchar[]) {
    a->firstname = firstchar;
}
```

The gcc throws this:

> incompatible types in assignment of `char*' to`char[0u]'

How to solve this problem?
Thanks for help!

Comment: Shouldn't you have `struct person * a` as the formal parameter?  You are missing `struct`.

Comment: @unxnut the OP is probably using a C++ compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot assign to an array. you want either a pointer, or copy the content of one into another.

```
struct person {
    char* firstname;
};

void abcde (person* a, char firstchar[]) { 
    a->firstname = firstchar;
}
```

`firstchar` in the function parameters is a *pointer*, not an array! the `[]` is merely a syntactic convenience. This is not the case for `char firstname[];`, which is an array.